# Ubuntu 22.04 kernel 6.5.0-21 and r8168-dkms (r8168-dkms : Depends: dkms (>= 3.0.3-4~) but 2.8.7-2ubuntu2.2 is installed)

Tags: drivers, apt, kernel, dependencies

So I have Ubuntu 22.04 with RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller. When I'm using the standard driver, my network disconnects every time. That's why I had to remove the driver and install r8168.

Everything was fine with kernel 6.2.0-39, but after I updated it to 6.5.0-21, I encountered an error during `apt-get update`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 r8168-dkms : Depends: dkms (>= 3.0.3-4~) but 2.8.7-2ubuntu2.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Now I wonder how I can solve this issue.

If I execute `apt --fix-broken install`, it will fix it by removing the r8168-dkms package. This is fine until the next reboot because after the reboot, my LAN network won't work.

Can I update dkms without breaking my system?

Comment: Search the launchpad bug site for r8169 dkms and add yourself to the appropriate bugs.  On Ubuntu 22.04, r8168-dkms should depend upon dkms >= 2.1.0.0, so your 2.8.7 should be fine, but... New kernels added to LTS releases may need new compilers, and those should be brought in via dependency (in dkms, which looks like it got slipstreamed in, since my dkms version is the same as yours, and has it now). Bugs may suggest workarounds till this gets fixed.

Comment: Thanks @ubfan1 that's might be the way to go.